# How to replace letters in lines in fasta file using bash loops?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to change all `n` in the sequence into `-`, but I don't know how to make my bash script not change the `n` that show up in sequence names. I'm not experienced with sed or regex to make sure my bash script reads only the lines that do not start with `>`, as that indicates the header.

Example file:

```
>Name_with_nnn
nnnatgcnnnatttg
>Name2_with_nnn
atgggnnnnGGtnnn
```

At the same time I want to convert all lowercase letters into uppercase, only in the sequence lines. I don't even know how to begin using sed, I find it really tricky to understand.

Expected output:

```
>Name_with_nnn
---ATGC---ATTTG
>Name2_with_nnn
ATGGG----GGT---
```

So after I created my sequence files I tried to continue my script with:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
     if [[ $line == ">"* ]]
     then
          echo "Ignoring header line: $line"
     else
          echo "Converting to uppercase and then N-to-gaps"
          # sed or tr?? do call $line or do I call $OUTFILE? so confused..
     fi
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve this with [`sed`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) with below line:

```
sed -i "/^>/! {s/n/-/g; s/\(.*\)/\U\1/g}" text.txt
```

And your output would be:

```
>Name_with_nnn
---ATGC---ATTTG
>Name2_with_nnn
ATGGG----GGT---
```

Comment: @DNAngel be aware I updated the script as converting to uppercase was missing.

Comment: @CedricZoppolo  Not only uppercase, you updated `start with` `>` too, might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Tiw is correct. I also updated to ensure only lines not starting with `>` will be converted. I was missing `^` character in order to get the lines starting with `>` and not lines containing such character in any part of line.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this simple `gnu sed`:

```
sed '/^>/!{s/n/-/g; s/.*/\U&/;}' file
```

```
>Name_with_nnn
---ATGC---ATTTG
>Name2_with_nnn
ATGGG----GGT---
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure Bash, likely quite slow for larger inputs:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    case $line in
        '>'*)
            printf '%s\n' "$line"
            ;;
        *)
            line=${line//n/-}
            printf '%s\n' "${line^^}"
            ;;
    esac
done < infile
```

This uses a [`case` statement](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-case) with pattern matching to test if a line starts with `>` or not; to modify the lines, [parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) are used. The `${parameter^^}` expansion requires Bash 4.0 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

How about `awk` ?

```
awk '/^[^>]/{gsub("n","-");print toupper($0);next;}1' data
```

Output:

```
>Name_with_nnn
---ATGC---ATTTG
>Name2_with_nnn
ATGGG----GGT---
```

However, `sed` can do it too (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^[^>]/{s/n/-/g;s/(.*)/\U\1/g;}' data
```

It's the same as:

```
sed -E '/^>/!{s/n/-/g;s/(.*)/\U\1/g;}' data
```

If you want to change in place, you can add `-i` switch to `sed`.